# void pointer as argument

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, argument-passing, void-pointers

The following C snippet:

```
[...] 
void f1(void* a){
  printf("f(a) address = %p \n",a);
  a = (void*)(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

  printf("a address = %p \n",a);
  *(int*)a = 3;

  printf("data = %d\n",*(int*)a);
}

void f(void){
  void* a1=NULL;
  printf("a1 address = %p \n",a1);

  f1(a1);

  printf("a1 address = %p \n",a1);
  printf("Data.a1 = %d\n",*(int*)a1);
}
[...]
```

results in

```
a1 address = (nil) 
f(a) address = (nil) 
a address = 0xb3f010 
data = 3
a1 address = (nil) 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why doesn't `a1` keep the address that has been assigned to it in the function?

Comment: Look up "pass by value".

Comment: Because you pass it by value.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As this is C, you cannot pass the pointer by reference without passing in a pointer to the pointer (e.g., `void **` rather than `void *` to point to the pointer). You need to return the new pointer. What is happening:

```
f(a1);
```

Pushes the value of the pointer (`NULL`) as the stack parameter value for `a`. `a` picks up this value, and then reassigns itself a new value (the `malloc`ed address). As it was passed by value, nothing changes for `a1`.

If this were C++, you could achieve what you want by passing the pointer by reference:

```
void f(void *&a);
```

Comment: In C, you can do that with `void f(void **a)`.

Comment: @chris Good point. Brain fart moment.

Answer (score 10):

Passing a pointer to `a1` to your function, you *can't* change where `a1` points. The pointer is *passed by value*, so in `f1` you're only changing a copy of the address held by `a`. If you want to change the pointer, i.e. allocate new memory for the pointer passed in, then you'll need to pass a *pointer to a pointer*:

```
void f1(void **a)
{
    // ...
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    // ...
```

Answer (score 5):

To change a variable via a function call, the function needs to have *reference semantics* with respect to the argument. C doesn't have native reference variables, but can implement reference semantics by means of taking addresses and passing pointers.

Generally:

```
void mutate_thing(Thing * x)    // callee accepts pointer
{
    *x = stuff;                 // callee derefences ("*")
}

int main()
{
    Thing y;
    mutate_thing(&y);           // caller takes address-of ("&")
}
```

In your case, the `Thing` is `void *`:

```
void f(void ** pv)
{
    *pv = malloc(12);   // or whatever
}

int main()
{
     void * a1;
     f(&a1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kerrek SB's example I came with this to demonstrate void pointer-to-pointer as an argument and how it may be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(void ** jeez)
{
  *jeez = (void *) (int) 3;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
void *a;
test(&a);

int b = *(int *)&a;
printf("value returned = %d\n", b);

return 0;
}
```