# Roots of cubic using C and GSL

Tags: c, gsl

I am trying to write a C program using GSL to find the roots of a cubic equation following the instructions here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Cubic-Equations.html. This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_poly.h>

double *x0,*x1,*x2;
int roots;

int
main (void)
{
    roots = gsl_poly_solve_cubic(0,0,0,x0,x1,x2);

    printf( " %d ", roots);

    return 0;
}
```

The arguments are 0,0,0 because I wanted to test if it works first. The code compiles but when run, it crashes with no output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x0, x1 and x2 are just dangling pointers - change the code to:

```
double x0,x1,x2;
int roots;

int
main (void)
{
    roots = gsl_poly_solve_cubic(0,0,0,&x0,&x1,&x2);

    printf( " %d ", roots);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh right...gosh that was silly! Thanks, will accept in 10 mins. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding how reference semantics are implemented in C. Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449034/596781) I just wrote on the exact same topic.

**Solution:**

```
double x0, x1, x2;

int roots = gsl_poly_solve_cubic(0, 0, 0, &x0, &x1, &x2);
```

**Nutshell:** The caller must take the address-of the recipient variable. The recipient variable must *exist*.

Answer (score 1):

According to you lonk we have `gsl_poly_solve_cubic (double a, double b, double c, double * x0, double * x1, double * x2)`. You declare 3 double pointers without allocating any memory ... this will result in a segfault.
Try to declare double variables and just pass their address :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_poly.h>


double x0,x1,x2;
int roots;

int
main (void)
{
    roots = gsl_poly_solve_cubic(0,0,0,&x0,&x1,&x2);

    printf( " %d ", roots);

    return 0;
}
```